# Exporting Summary Boxes

Tags: output-formatting, formatting, elided-forms

I would like to Export a Summary Box in its expanded Form. How do i do this? 
I can Export a collapsed Summary Box by doing:

```
result = ConvolutionLayer[4,8] (*which is a summary Box*)
Export["testFile.pdf", result]
```

Comment: Interactively you can expand the summary box and then right-click on the cell bracket and select "Save selection as", but it would be nice to be able to do that programmatically

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*edit: simplified code and an explanation*

I could bet I already answered that in the past but can't find. The solution works as follows:

What you see is a box expression (`MakeBoxes[result of evaluation]`) rendered by the FrontEnd. You can inspect it via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> or by applying `ToBoxes` on your expression. The latter allows you to work with boxes and modify them.

After inspection we see that it is roughly `DynamicModule[{open = False}, PaneSelector[...]...`. So we want to replace `False` with `True` in order to make the initial pane open. You can later use `RawBoxes` or `DisplayForm` to preview results or to make `Export` export its rendered form instead of raw box expression.

```
result = ConvolutionLayer[4,8];

result // 
  ToBoxes // 
  ReplaceAll[ HoldPattern[Typeset`open = _] :> (Typeset`open = True)] // 
  RawBoxes //  
  Export["test.pdf", #] &
```

[image]

Comment: `Unevaluated` also works for this, ```ReplaceAll[
 HoldPattern[Typeset`open = False] :> 
  Unevaluated[Typeset`open = True]]```

Comment: @JasonB. Good for you :p I find it hard to use `Unevaluated` for more than simple things so I don't use it ;)

Comment: This is in a `Hold...` structure so you don't even need to `Hold`. You can just do something like ``HoldPattern[Typeset`open = _] :> (Typeset`open = True)``

Comment: @b3m2a1 you are right, guess I shouldn't have skipped my 3rd coffee. Will correct it tomorrow.

Comment: @Kuba Thanks for giving me this insight. Do you also know how i can ommit the ConvolutionLayer[]?

Comment: @Gladaed try ``(result // ToBoxes // 
    ReplaceAll[
     HoldPattern[Typeset`open = _] :> (Typeset`open = True)]) /. 
  RowBox[{___, DMB_DynamicModuleBox, ___}] :> DMB // RawBoxes``

Comment: @Kuba That does work but only on ConvolutionalLayer not on other objects like NetTrainResultsObject. My solution in https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/192589/exporting-summary-boxes-headless seems to be more universal althoug way less beautifull.