# Exporting Summary Boxes - Headless

Tags: output-formatting, elided-forms

This question is a follow up question to [Exporting Summary Boxes](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/190937/exporting-summary-boxes).

When cutting away the "Head" of a summary box is there a better way than doing the following?

```
result = ConvolutionLayer[4, 8];

boxData = (result // ToBoxes // 
  ReplaceAll[HoldPattern[Typeset`open = _] :> (Typeset`open = True)] )  
boxData[[1, 1, 1, 1, 3]] // RawBoxes
```

Since just accessing the particular element seems very inelegant and might be prone to errors in the future. Ideally it would cut the + aswell.

Answer (score 1):

Peering into the structure returned, you seem to want the contents of the `DynamicModuleBox`:

```
Cases[boxData, _DynamicModuleBox, Infinity];
RawBoxes@%
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]